# Flagged a question as rude/abusive, then edited question resulting in disputed flag

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags, rude-or-abusive

I guess this will be more of a question for 10k users, as this question has already been removed by moderation.

Today I saw a post insulting the dear SO members, and a claim that the user therefore always makes throw away accounts.

I first custom flagged the post as rude/abusive, then edited the rude part out of the question (though it of course stays in the edit log), and then noticed that my custom flag got marked as [disputed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3231537?group=3&status=4).

This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742192/c-sharp-calculation-always-equals-50-percent) which I flagged.

My question is now, should I just have edited the rude part out, and custom flag it with the remark that a mod should check the edit history, or edit and then mark it as rude/abusive?

Since the post is now removed, does that mean that one mod did agree?

Comment: You are a gentleman.  You handled it very well.  As a member of the SO community, I think of myself as one of thousands of volunteers who are just trying to help people, and a comment like that attacking the SO community in the question really, really pisses me off.  (Then again, I _am_ an [8 on the Enneagram](https://www.enneagraminstitute.com/type-8/))

Comment: @cale_b I was mainly very surprised, which caused my action of flagging before then thinking, wait.... I can edit it out :)

Comment: As a general suggestion for the future.  Any time what you're flagging isn't immediately obvious - eg because you edited it out - use a custom flag with an explanation of what the problem is and how to see the evidence.  The moderator flag queue is reportedly limited in the context it makes immediately available to the reviewer.  Anything not blindingly obvious is at risk of being not seen unless the moderator goes actively looking for it.

Comment: @DanNeely So I should have retracted the rude/abusive flag after I edited it, and then give a custom flag to look through the edit history? Good to know, thank you

Comment: If I intended to edit, I'd go with the custom flag off the bat.  Either flagging after editing, or noting that I was going to edit the flame out after raising the flag.

Comment: @DanNeely That's the thing, I was so surprised that my first reaction was to flag it, I only thought about editing it out like 5 minutes later :D I guess then I could have retracted my previous flag and add a custom one

Comment: @Icepickle I don't think you can re-flag after retracting a flag, but I might be wrong. Maybe re-flag with a custom flag after the flag got set to disputed if the mods didn't already take further action. Or you could ask someone to raise a custom flag for you in chat somewhere. (I dunno if [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) would appreciate that or not.)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In cases where the entire question wasn't intended as being offensive / trolling, but has a section edited into it that was, we tend to remove that section and clear (dispute) the offensive flag. Disputed flags don't work against you, and act as if the flag was never cast.

Validating the flag turns the question into an audit case if deleted, and can impose serious penalties on the asker. That's why we're a little more cautious about accepting those.

However, the part that had been edited in ("Your karma whore system is why I create throwaway accounts.") indicated to us that this was a question-ban evasion account, so their account was destroyed and an IP block imposed. This automatically deleted the question, because downvoted questions are deleted by the system on deletion of the parent account.

You did the right thing by editing that wording out, and I definitely would have marked as helpful a custom flag that points out them indicating that they said they were creating throwaway accounts.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info, guess he didn't do himself a favor there :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It's very useful to understand how things work behind the scenes, helps people like me sharpen our use of the SO system.

Comment: A TL;DR might be nice: "Yes, edit the question; also raise a custom flag about the ban evasion."

Comment: @jpmc26 That seems very similar to the last sentence in this post.

Comment: @TinyGiant It is, but it's not clear that the last sentence might be a TL;DR. ;) Would be nice to call it out as such if so. Also, one of the things my writing teachers emphasized in school was that if you put your thesis in the essay early, your readers will have an easier time following you since they know where you're headed with everything.

Comment: I didn't really think the post was TL to R.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Posts with helpful R/A flags (not spam) are now explicitly excluded from appearing as audits.

Comment: Well, that *explains* but does not *justify* why the flag is marked as "disputed".

Comment: @Raedwald - That might just be a problem with wording. Listing these flags as "disputed" is an artifact of the way this third category of flag response (vs. the positive "helpful" and negative "declined") came about. Given the fact that this is a neutral state (doesn't help or harm both flagger and recipient, there was some merit in the original flag), perhaps it might be time to look at renaming this state to "removed", "cleared", or something that better reflects its current use.