# An asker inserted insults in a question edit; a ‘rude or abusive’ flag was raised in response. Why was it disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags, rude-or-abusive

After two edits to a post to remove salutations (and fix typos) the OP rolled back the revisions and edited this into the post:

> Edit: Can you like Fuckoff Mr. *"insert user name"* ? what a shitty hostile website, go ahead and ban me. So insisting on removing "Thank you in advance"

Why was the rude or abusive flag *disputed*?

This also raises an issue that the revision that addressed the editor by name is still in the revision history.

Comment: Was the whole post rude or abusive? If not, then I kind of agree with the dispute; you are flagging the entire post after all. You would have been better off raising a custom flag in my opinion, disengaging and (optionally) rolling back the edit.

Comment: @Larnu rolling-back would have been wrong since the OP was already engaged in a roll-back war.

Comment: I would, personally, suggest that rolling back rude and abusive language is never wrong; regardless of rollback wars. If a rollback war was already in effect, then disengage sooner next time; as such things already raise automatic flags for the mods.

Comment: A problem there is that custom post flags tend to take longer to process than "red flags", so the rudeness could be there for weeks and is a major "broken window". I likely would've gone rude or abusive too and it's good to get official guidance on cases like this.

Comment: @Larnu the editor never engaged to begin with. The first and second edits were normal and they didn't even notice the first roll-back, it was just normal tag clean-up.

Comment: Then just roll it back and leave it at that, @bad_coder . That would have raised a mod flag automatically, and then if the OP was abusive again the mods would have handled it. The question here, at least to me, implied the OP rollbacks multiple times, due to you saying that "they rolled back revisions" (plural), so I inferred that there was more than one rollback by the OP.

Comment: @Larnu correct the OP rolled back twice, the editor edited the 2nd time without noticing the 1st roll-back.

Comment: Then i stand by what I said, rollback, and let the automatic flag be raised. Of course, a mod may have a different opinion, but I don't completely see the reason to raise it as rude/abusive if the entire post isn't (and hence why i agree with disputed, as the entire post likely wasn't).

Comment: The linked duplicate is different from this post because it's about a single word while the post in this question addressed the editor by name to insult them explicitly.

Comment: Since when does it matter the "kind of rudeness" displayed? That's immaterial to the flag.

Comment: @yivi The rollbacks matter. I'd like to see a mod confirm this guidance still holds if the rudeness is blatant insults and gets rolled back.

Comment: @ErikA The dupes deal with this scenario, and with the outcome (e.g. flag being disputed instead of being declined).

Comment: The "edit" is noise @bad_coder but I agree this is not a duplicate. The order of operations/direction of what's going on here is reversed from each of the duplicates.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this is your flag and not a flag of someone else? Is that correct?

Comment: @TylerH yes, I did raise the flag.

Comment: if the user doesn't want your edits and rollsback, let them be, why do you edit them twice, if it was clear that it wasn't wanted

Comment: @nbk you didn't read the clarification in the comments, an editor doesn't necessarily notice that an edit was rolled back if they stumble across the same post a few days or weeks later. (You realize that [removing salutations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778) is a standard editing guideline?)

Comment: @bad_coder i jonw that is a valid edit, and your first edit was godd, but the user doesn_'t want your edits at all, which he showed by removing your edits, and then it is the best way to let it be and let other take care of it or edit and ediot againa and again till the user gives up. re rool back also some edits on my post, when o really want them the  way i  posted it

Comment: Whether or not the user wants the edits is irrelevant when it comes to removing this kind of content.

Comment: Does approval of a R/A flag on a question cause immediate action on the question, such as deletion?

Comment: @KevinB No. If a mod marks it "helpful", all it does is mark the flag as helpful. There are certain actions that auto-fulfill flags (like a mod deleting something with open flags on it), but not vice versa.

Comment: @nbk a poster does not "own" the post they made - as soon as they hit the submisson button, they irrevocably licensed their post under the CC-BY-SA conditions which includes free modification. An OP disliking an edit is no ground to let it be 'cause they "do not want it" - this should not even be a consideration when editing - the only thing that *does* matter is if the post is left in a better shape as before.

Comment: More on point, @bad_coder - I too was in a similar situation once, and even got the flag  declined (complained it back to disputed in the end, though). Guess it is really best to edit, wait for the OP to roll back and raise a custom flag when it happens (to avoid a rollback war) - this is a sure way of dealing with the problem for good.

Comment: @TylerH Afaik marking a red flag (spam/R/A) on a post helpful does punish the user that made the post (hinted by a mod [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351257/7296893)). Possibly the mods have some tricks up their sleeve to avoid it, but I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: I realize this was already used as a target, and then reopened, but now that a mod has answered this specific question with the same response as given by another mod on the linked target, it's quite clear that it's the same issue.

Comment: Related: *[When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post/127655#127655)*

Comment: Since reopening [clears the additional dupe targets from the linked section](https://imgur.com/a/vNnLBK2), I'm adding the other posts here as references: [In what cases can the "offensive" flag be used?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307385/1426539), [Flags are declined because an edit was made afterwards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391869/1426539). @TylerH check the screenshot, you may want to revisit your previous comment.

Comment: This should probably have been tagged as support rather than discussion, since it is about a specific issue. @yivi It doesn't make sense to close specific support issues as duplicates. Sure there isn't much to discuss since we aren't given access/a link to the original post, but at least moderators will have access to the flag history of the poster.

Comment: @Lundin the question is a duplicate. And your answer here belongs here as much as in any of the duplicates. Let's agree to disagree in what makes sense or not.

Comment: @yivi The question is about a _specific_, unique incident and asking why a specific flag was declined. You cannot close a unique incident as a duplicate by definition. I'm going to re-tag this to support now because the discussion tag doesn't make any sense.

Comment: By definition, I could, and I did, @Lundin. Specific incidents are still subject to general rules and practices. Do as you please, but do not ping me just to repeat yourself, please.

Comment: @yivi Meta doesn't work like that. It's not just a place to discuss the general use/moderation of the site, but it is also a place where any user is welcome to raise an informal support ticket about a specific issue or ask for help about site mechanics. You cannot close that because someone had a similar issue back in 2015! This being an unique issue aside: back in 2015 this was an utterly different site with completely different culture, different CoC, different community consensus, different moderation and so on.

Comment: @Lundin Meta **does** work like that as well. Please stop strying to instruct me, just accept we disagree and move on.

Comment: @yivi It's not a matter of agreeing or disagreeing, moderation isn't carried out based on opinions, but based on policies and community consensus of how the site works. Feel free to make counter-arguments if you think I have misunderstood any of those policies...

Comment: @yivi Thanks, I didn't realize additional dupe targets are cleared during re-opening... is that just on Meta, I wonder? Given that questions linked from comments stay in the Linked section even after the comment is deleted, it seems pretty weird to have the behavior we're experiencing here... I hope it isn't the case on main sites.

Comment: @Zoe Do you think it is a good idea as a moderator to close down [tag:discussion] and/or [tag:support] meta threads regarding inconsistent/incorrect moderator actions currently happening with the current moderator team, as a duplicate to some meta posts from 2015/2017? (When an entirely different CoC was used.)

Comment: @Lundin That sounds like a separate Meta question to me.

Answer (score -88, accepted):

It was disputed because the remedy - open to anyone - was to edit out the profanity laden attack. There was no need to get the moderators involved. It would have also been quicker than flagging and waiting for a moderator to see and act on the flag.

If the OP had reinserted it then I would have been more likely to mark the flag as helpful and even take further action if it was warranted.

The goal of moderation is to defuse situations like this as quickly and quietly as possible. A third party stepping in to edit the post would have done that.

I handled the flag in the way I did because I thought it was a one-off and uncharacteristic for the user. I didn't think that it warranted deleting the post with a rude/abusive flag thus giving the user a 100 point reputation penalty.

Comment: What is the mod's position on redacting the timeline to remove the personal attack by name from the history?

Comment: @bad_coder That sounds like [a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I'm not objecting to answering that, but you're basically asking for policy, which I don't recall being specifically discussed. It's something that reasonably deserves its own discussion in a wider forum than just in comments here. I would, however, note that even if the post was deleted as R/A, it would still be in the edit history.

Comment: @Makyen I agree, I consider it a relevant issue that should be discussed separately.

Comment: I don't think there's any particular need to change the historical record.  The edits remove the ad hominem attack from casual view — you would have to be searching hard to come across the attack.  In particular, it is likely that only experienced SO users would ever see it after the edit is in place.

Comment: This seems like trying to foist a catch-22 onto readers. They already had their edits rolled back by OP, yet your suggestion is... edit the post? Is there official guidance on how many times users should rollback/edit before flagging? Is the answer "always at least one more than you did"?

Comment: @TylerH I checked the history, and I can't see where the attack was reinstated, which is what we're talking about here isn't it? The roll back of the previous edits is an example of something we see a lot and in those cases we do say walk away to avoid inflaming the situation.

Comment: @ChrisF No, I'm talking about what OP said above. The question was edited to remove noise **twice**, and then the OP rolled the edits back _and introduced a rude message_. Why should the rude message also have to be edited out (via a _third revision_) when OP is clearly sending a message they intentionally want to be rude and keep noise or harmful content into their post? It sounds like you're saying three edits is not enough here. Or at least, that OP editing _in_ harmful content has to itself be rolled back, even if the harmful content was introduced in _response to_ initial edits.

Comment: Which seems... excessive.

Comment: "There was no need to get the moderators involved" Cool, the CoC has been silently changed again? Because it looks the same https://stackoverflow.com/conduct.  I've been given moderator warnings for telling people that they can find the answer to their question in the first chapter of a beginner-level book of the topic. I've never told anyone to f* off however. Consistent moderation much?

Comment: @Lundin. It all depends on the context and whether I think it's part of a pattern of behaviour or a one off. In this case I thought it was a one-off and unlikely to be repeated.

Comment: @ChrisF From the CoC: "Enforcement. We take your reports seriously. Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team. This is how moderators generally handle misconduct: Warning **For most first-time misconduct, moderators will remove offending content and send a warning**. Most issues are resolved here. " Is the CoC wrong or do you follow a different one?

Comment: @Lundin moderators now have to babysit every post that has a rude commentary? Come on! Anyone can remove the offending content, no need to involve a moderator just to "edit".

Comment: @Braiam There's a quite a difference between rude/gruff/snark comments etc and hurling outright insults and profane language targeted at another user.

Comment: Whelp, I bid good luck to whoever moderator is put in charge of issuing warnings and suspensions for every single piece of rude commentary that shows up on the platform.

Comment: I'm getting very mixed signals from the moderator team. One month ago I received a moderator warning for posting this comment: "This is very basic stuff. You should study the if statement, arrays, pointers and strings in your favourite beginner-level C book."  This is clearly not acceptable behavior - instead I should have written "Can you like Fuckoff Mr. "insert user name" ? what a shitty hostile website" and that would have been fine. If this isn't hypocrisy and wildly inconsistent moderation, then I don't know what is.

Comment: @Lundin that's because the CoC puts more scrutiny on established members than on new/low participation ones. Basically, different yardsticks to go by. Once you accept that you, Lundin, are held to a different standard, everything makes sense.

Comment: @Braiam As in, it is fine for new users stumbling in from google to throw a tantrum and hurling profanities. Then do the same next week under a new account. But veteran users that have been contributing to the site for 10+ years and done their fair share of site moderation themselves should be constantly harassed. No, I'm not going to accept that. If that's truly how the site is moderated, then the solution is to stop using this site.

Comment: @Braiam Also, quotation needed "the CoC puts more scrutiny on established members". I can't find this in the CoC. Am I missing something here or you too using a different one than https://stackoverflow.com/conduct?

Comment: @Lundin I mean, you will not find it in public writing, but remember when the CoC was first updated?

Comment: @Lundin You're missing a really big and important difference between the two scenarios: questions can be edited by **anyone with at least [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)**; comments **can only be removed by the comment's author or a moderator**. Which is **exactly** the justification given in this answer: that the situation was better handled by the user themselves by editing, than adding to a moderator's workload by flagging.

Comment: @Braiam I remember a certain incident when someone had their moderator rights removed for not following non-existent text in the CoC. Supposedly moderators will be held to even higher standards than veteran users. To the point where there doesn't need to be a reason for taking disciplinary actions against them. So yeah you may have a point that the higher the expectations on a user, the more likely they are to be disciplined through subjective moderation based on whims, opinions and moods by individual moderators and CMs. But do we _want_ that system?

Comment: @IMSoP Edit wars, as was apparently the case here, can only be resolved by moderators though, so there not as big a difference as you think. Also, these kind of issues should be moderator priorities. If they have a big workload, they can skip out on lower priority, mostly pointless busy-work like tag burnination, "no longer needed" comment clean-up, migrating discussions to chat etc.

Comment: @Lundin It wasn't an "edit war" that was flagged, though, it was a single edit introducing profanity, which did _not_ require moderator attention to remove. The answer even states quite clearly that if the OP _had_ persisted in adding it, then further action would have been taken. Similarly, if the text had been in a comment, it would surely have been deleted _because no non-moderator can do anything about it_.

Comment: @IMSoP Regardless, you are missing the entire point that disciplinary actions by moderators should be handed out based on user behavior, not based on how convenient it is for regular users to remove such unacceptable content. It's not ok to tell someone to f* off just because it was made inside a question/answer or because it is easy for other users to remove that. Speaking of different standards, I was under the impression that we also held questions/answers to a higher standard than comments.

Comment: @IMSoP "*comments can only be removed by the comment's author or a moderator*" This is not completely true; anyone can flag a comment as NLN or Rude. In some cases (if the comment contains a curse word like the F word mentioned above), the comment will auto-delete *the first time it is flagged*.

Comment: @Braiam "moderators now have to babysit every post that has a rude commentary" - given that dealing with rule-breaking is one of the core responsibilities of being a moderator... yes. Every post with rude commentary should go through the moderation process. So you would rather have users freely insult others as often as they want without any consequences, as long as they put it in a post (so it can be edited out)? If yes, then that sounds like it would be a pretty miserable site. If no, then how do you expect mods to become aware of a user regularly insulting others, if not through flags?

Comment: This is the first post I have seen with a -47 vote tally that was accepted. Like, greyed out because it's likely wrong and not worth reading, but accepted ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica [There are plenty of others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1319&tab=Votes&q=is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3a1). Most like this one are posts by a moderator or staff member so they're technically the "correct" answer to the question, but the community overwhelmingly disagreed with the reasoning behind them.

Comment: @Lundin "not following non-existent text in the CoC" You mean, the non-CoC.

Comment: "The goal of moderation is to defuse situations like this" So you think that editing in the middle of an edit war content that is about the edit war is "defusing" (by users).

Comment: Memo to myself:

According to the mod team it is totally fine to swear, abuse or insult other people as long as you do it inside questions (or answers) and not more than once per question/answer since anyone can edit out the slurs etc. and doing it once is not a "edit war" etc.

Comment: @CharonX no it's not. I handled this flag in this way because I thought it was a one off that wouldn't be repeated and taking it further would make things worse. I appear to have been wrong in that assessment.

Comment: @ChrisF When someone demonstrates such behavior, they need a swift and strong message that their actions will not be tolerated here. They don't need their behavior swept under the rug. Make it clear to them that they either abide by the CoC and treat people with respect, or they are not welcome here.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "given that dealing with rule-breaking is one of the core responsibilities of being a moderator" no, they are not. They are human exception handlers, someone having a post with something rude can be dealt by users, like spam, closing, etc. You only need a moderator if you don't have the tools to deal with the situation.

Comment: @Braiam If it was that simple as a moderator being someone with a few more tools, then we could just have everyone unlock full moderator privileges at 30k rep or so. They are not just "exception handlers" or "janitors", they are also the police force and judges all in one. The reason why we hold elections is to find people who the community trusts when it comes to resolving conflicts, which involves handing out suspensions. Ideally after some consistent moderation policy. Then we have a company (the benevolent dictator) who likes to have a CoC that moderators supposedly should enforce.

Comment: @Lundin they are "exception handlers" and "janitors", and also "role models". They are not supposed to go out to patrol for "rule breaking" but to address concerns that the community can't handle. They have several more powers that the company, understandably, do not want anyone but trusted community members to have: access to PII, ability to destroy any and every account, etc. If anything, they are clerks of the court or judges, rather than police.

Answer (score 98):

If the text as quoted was present in a post or comment, then it's pretty much a crystal clear violation of several bullets of the site's [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). This flag should obviously never have been disputed and these kind of offensive posts must absolutely get flagged for moderator attention, not just to remove it, but to take disciplinary actions against the user who posted it.

Moderators can make mistakes too, so normally I wouldn't make a fuss about this. But given the unacceptable answer you got from a moderator here "There was no need to get the moderators involved.", I would recommend escalating this to Community Managers, because clearly some moderators are confused about what their duties are. Sure, regular users can and should edit out offensive content, but we should also flag such to moderators who can hand out warnings or suspensions.

Comment: Better think about what we really want moderators to be: agents of de-escalation... or agents of punishment. The former may involve a bit of the latter, but that doesn't mean we get to shift the goal post.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator I want moderators to moderate the site _consistently_ and after some sort of consensus, such as the mandatory Code of Conduct. I don't want them to make decisions based on whims, mood or personal opinions.

Comment: Interesting take. If, instead of a well-written meta question, the OP would have whined on twitter about a blatant insult in violation of the CoC and the flag on it being disputed, and had at least a modest following, imagine the response the company would've had.

Comment: @ErikA Yes, it is a sad state of affairs. But in all fairness I don't think anyone _has_ actually escalated this to CMs though, so we can't really accuse the company of being ignorant. Sure, it would be common sense to have employees monitor their own flag ship product, so that it isn't allowed to lose credibility like this, but that's another story.

Comment: Genuine question: other than removing the content, what is the action you would like the moderator to have taken in this case? There has been mention of "issuing a warning", but I'm not sure what this actually looks like to the user. In my experience, new users have no understanding of the difference between high-rep users, moderators, and staff, so would they understand the difference between this "official warning" and a comment on the question from a normal user?

Comment: @IMSoP You get a notification and an email. It looks quite different from a regular user notification.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator I definitely want moderators to act on intentional, deliberate defacement of posts that also include offensive language targeted at specific users, even if it's a first-time offense. At the **very least**, I want them to consider flags re: such behavior to be _helpful_. That's exactly the kind of user moderation that elected moderators are uniquely positioned (and elected) to deal with.

Comment: While you are technically correct there is in my opinion no need to get all wound up over verbal abuse. The wise simply ignore it and grace more important and worthwhile things with their attention. And please don't start with a code of conduct which is the product of people who have too much time on their hands with too little to do.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The core problem here isn't that the mods think they can ignore verbal abuse, but that the level of moderation is completely inconsistent. As I wrote in another comment thread, moderators gave me a warning one month ago for posting this comment: "This is very basic stuff. You should study the if statement, arrays, pointers and strings in your favourite beginner-level C book." This was apparently enough for the moderator team to take disciplinary actions. I should supposedly have written "f* off (name), go read a book and don't use this shitty website" instead.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure why you mentioned me there. Moderators should indeed act, act well, and preferably act as soon as possible.

Comment: @Lundin Ts ts. Scaring away new customers? Capital offense.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Nah, the company has never realized that the users of the site are their (potential or existing) customers. Though I don't quite see how telling new customers to outright f* off instead would be an improvement in that regard.

Comment: @Lundin "*This was apparently enough for the moderator team to take disciplinary actions.*" No, I very seriously doubt that. If that was the *only* problematic comment you'd ever posted then I agree completely that any disciplinary action was unwarranted. My guess is that this is very far from your first such offense.

Comment: @cigien They also gave a couple of other very similar "you should read the first chapters of a book" comments as reason. The moderator gave some meta post as rationale and quoted "it might be a basic question, but that in itself is no reason to prevent having it asked and answered on Stack Overflow." Basically the moderator didn't like that I was remarking on users who use SO as an interactive beginner tutorial instead of reading the first chapters of beginner-level learning material. Which used to be a firm requirement before posting on SO, before the $$$quantity$$$ over quality era.

Comment: @cigien Other than that, I think I got a warning at another time maybe 5-6 years back. Again, for those who actually bothered to read the CoC: "For most first-time misconduct, moderators will remove offending content and send a warning." If it wasn't my first offence, then the moderators would be even more inconsistent in case they chose to send a warning "whenever they feel like" rather than as stated in the CoC. Are you saying this is the case?

Comment: 1) I don't know what the requirements used to be a long time ago, but policies change over time. I know you understand that because you clearly feel this particular meta shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of posts that are several years old, since policy might have changed. 2) The warnings you received seem reasonable to me, even if you only got a warning on later offenses, instead of the first one. The CoC you quoted does say "most", not "all". Anyway, I'm sure you can poke at the language all day long, but you do seem to have missed the spirit of the warnings, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @cigien Nah I got the spirit of the warnings and it seems to be "As a moderator I am above the CoC and I can therefore hand out arbitrary warnings whenever I feel like. I don't like that you think that posters should actually know something about the topic they are asking about." I did send a message back asking along the lines of what exactly in the CoC that prevents us from prompting new users in comments about making an effort into knowing the utter minimum about the topic they are asking about, but no reply.

Comment: This is starting to get off-topic, but may I ask why you want to "prompt" new users into making an effort at all? In your experience, does that actually work? Also, it's not really our place as users to give other users such advice, is it? You *can* give such advice if you want, but it's actually very hard to do that without coming across as condescending. I'd suggest refraining from leaving such comments.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator I was replying to your comment, where you said "we better think about what we want moderators to be"

Comment: @cigien It admittedly leads nowhere, these kind of comments are just the result of frustration with the quality decay of this site. It used to be a site for professional/enthusiast programmers, see. (A programmer being someone with at least an utter minimum of knowledge about programming.) I try to just down vote too simple questions now, or close vote as simple typo/dupe vote if it's some uninteresting FAQ syntax error thing.

Answer (score 13):

While I didn't see the context, it sounds like it was a regular, unproblematic, on-topic post that the author later edited to add a personal attack.

That personal attack was not acceptable, no matter what.

However, "rude or abusive" (RA) isn't the right flag to use in this case, because of what it can do, namely deleting and locking the post (which would also delete its answers). A mod can mark the RA flag as helpful, but it automatically changes to disputed when the flags are cleared (which a moderator needs to do to reverse any affects of RA flags). I think that a rollback would have the same effect too, at least on a post that hasn't yet gotten 6 red flags. Remember, disputed flags don't count against the flagger.

In other words, a moderator doesn't have a choice: the flag *cannot* be marked helpful.

The correct outcome was for the post to be rolled back to an earlier state, potentially with additional steps to make it stay that way. Someone already tried to roll back (twice?) but that didn't work. In my opinion, continuing rolling back yourself wouldn't be a good option because you expect it's going to be immediately reverted by the author, and it's possibly opening yourself up to hostility.

Therefore, the correct option would have been a custom mod flag explaining the situation, including the rollback war. The moderator can do the rollback and has a lot more options at their disposal to make it stick (anything ranging from locking to mod messaging to an actual suspension), plus more information about the user's history than you.

In fact, as a moderator on another site, I would appreciate a custom flag about abusive language that crosses the line like this, even if you were to resolve this via a rollback by yourself. No action may happen because of it (especially not a visible one), but it helps keep moderators in the loop in case a pattern does develop.

---

As for redaction, this usually isn't done for abusive content because it obscures what actually happened (the original content and how it was changed). It's typically only used on private information or when it legally has to, ie DMCAs.

With the exception of comments (which leave a trail only for moderators), users can see abusive content in various places if they choose to. However, the system isn't perfect in this regard; you're probably a bit more likely to be in the revision history than stumbling across a rejected abusive suggested edit. Even deleted posts are clearly marked when they're offensive, which I believe is ideal for this type of content. With the tools we have right now, it's best to clearly explain the reason why you're rolling back, since older revisions will be collapsed.

Comment: This is a much more useful (and relevant) explanation for why a Rude/Abusive flag would be declined for this scenario. Do you know if moderators have reached out to SE staff to request an improvement to the options moderators have when handling R/A flags on posts (e.g. being able to mark them helpful without applying any lasting post penalty)?

Comment: @TylerH Not that I know of, because "disputed" is the way to mark a spam/RA flag as somewhat helpful, while not applying the penalties. The flag isn't "declined" (which would signal that flagging was a mistake) but it's also not "helpful" (since it wouldn't be good for an otherwise ok post to be deleted). However the system could probably do a lot better job of explaining what's happening.

Comment: "**mod messaging to an actual suspension**", this please. Would be nice to see mods that are actually driven by interaction instead of focusing on what flag choice to use.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth noting that the best course of action here would be the following.

1. Revert the inappropriate edit.
2. If you think that this might not be the last of it from that user, cast a *custom flag* on the post explaining the situation. Evidently, this case called for a flag due to the rollback war.

This gives us the best of both worlds: it puts a plug on the attack are while moderators are kept a record of the incident for any eventual repercussion towards the offender.

Flagging as rude/abusive is probably something that I would have liked to see as applicable to the situation, but it doesn't work so well due to how it's implemented in the system. When that flag is marked as helpful, this introduces two unilateral effects:

- The post is deleted and marked as abusive or spam.
- The post author loses 100 reputation points.

To the best of my knowledge, these effects are irreversible. Therefore, at least for as long as R/A flags behave this way, moderators will continue to be reluctant to applying such a penalty over a piece of offensive meta-commentary in an otherwise reasonable post. They are best reserved to posts which are unsalvageable to begin with. Custom flags for moderator attention do not have this problem, the disciplinary action can be taken based on the severity of the edit.

---

Should this ever result in a rollback war... well, that is just too bad. The guideline to avoid rollback wars may work fine in other cases, but when it comes to abuse, it should not be an excuse to leave offensive content unattended, because this is something that should not happen in the first place.

In the event that moderators are unable to attend to these events in a timely manner, then we have a problem more serious than a rollback war. It means that the platform has become a paradise playground for trolls.

See also:

- [In what cases can the "offensive" flag be used?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307383)
- [Flagged a question as rude/abusive, then edited question resulting in disputed flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351250)
- [How do the moderator resignations affect me and the community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/how-do-the-moderator-resignations-affect-me-and-the-community)

Comment: Reverting the inappropriate edit will further escalate though... How do you see it as a de-escalation? Not saying I disagree with the 'keep editing and report', but completely failing to understand the comment about again editing the post being a de-escalation?

Comment: @DavidMulder It's a choice between keeping the offensive meta-commentary and reverting it whenever it reappears. Hardly ideal, sure, but it's what we have available until a moderator comes around.

Comment: @DavidMulder wait, someone did exactly that and didn't escalate. So it seems that it works.